# Why is the cut-off corner of my div not smooth?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to cut off the corners and make it work on every browser including IE 11 (not necessary below).

I am using `background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) calc(100% - 30px), transparent 0);`

I just made the corner transparent, but using the 130deg is making the corner not smooth looking.

How to make it smooth?

```css
body {
background: black;
}
.item {
    padding: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) calc(100% - 30px), transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid delectus eligendi magnam necessitatibus alias error aspernatur ratione? Assumenda aperiam ipsa vitae numquam quas earum amet repudiandae perspiciatis quia, animi, facilis!
</div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/victoreugen2002/1bznkLs8/)

Comment: hi. try this it - background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 30px, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0);

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, answers go down there. You short-circuit the process when you put them in comments.

Comment: I don't think this question is actually a dupe of the question it's linked to.
If all you want is smooth corners in every browser, you should just use `border-radius` instead of a linear gradient in the background.